# Message Passing from Packaged App to Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing, google-chrome-app

I have seen [this article](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) about passing messages between extensions which works when you know the extension ids.

But, what I would really like to do is pass a message from a packaged app to an extension.
I tried to implement the steps in the article above. But i received the message that chrome.extension is not defined.

I assumed this is because it is a packaged app, that it doesnt have chrome.extension.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks
AH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cross-extension messaging
>
> In addition to sending messages between different components in your
>   extension, you can use the messaging API to communicate with other
>   extensions. This lets you expose a public API that other extensions
>   can take advantage of.
>
> Listening for incoming requests and connections is similar to the
>   internal case, except you use the runtime.onMessageExternal or
>   runtime.onConnectExternal methods.

http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/messaging.html

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish via [Web Intents](http://webintents.org/), specifically the "explicit" variant that can be targeted at a specific app/extension. See [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/explicit-webintents) in the apps repository for two apps that communicate via explicit Web Intents (the same concept can be applied to an extension and an app, except the extension would receive intents via a [URL specified in the manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#intents)).

Comment: Web intents are depricated in Chrome. http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-web-intents/2012Nov/0000.html